# Wamp VS PHP : absolutely fine & accessible image path seems broken

Tags: php, image, wamp, filepath

I have this very  strange problem:

If I use absolute url/paths as image sources within my HTML codes (localhost - WAMP) by using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` all of my images are broken and I don't know why :( 
PHP includes are absolutely fine with it, only my images are behaving strangely. The absolute image path itself (generated by `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` + my path variables) is working fine outside of localhost.(I have tried to copy and paste the url into my browser bar and the image shows up as expected. But in my localhost environment all images are broken) .

Example screenshot of this problem

[image]

As you can see here, my Chrome element inspector on link hover **shows completely different image paths** than the actual path created by `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, and this drives me crazy because whats in the HTML is the CORRECT path, not the other one.... Any ideas how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance!

---

here are my codes so far:

```
$sysvar_category_default_image="/design/category_images/category_default.jpg";

$path= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .$sysvar_category_default_image;
// $path is: C:/wamp64/www/design/category_images/category_default.jpg

$path= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .$sysvar_category_default_image;
// $path is: localhost/design/img/icons/default.png
```

Both path working correctly pasted in the browser bar (these are the correct, actual image paths ),but my WampServer messing them up somehow (  maybe it's a configuration issue but i'm really lost at this point)

Answer (score 4):

You are using document root? That is a local path and not a URL. Don't do that!

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` instead, or just ignore the domain and have absolute urls starting from `/`.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this also doesn't works for me :( The absolute path created with $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  is also "messed up" 
Here's an updated screenshot:  https://imgur.com/a/ERc1eCF

Comment: and what if you don't use the HTTP_HOST at all?

Comment: Relative paths work like a charm (at least if it comes to  displaying images) BUT I really want to solve this with full / absolute paths relative to the actual environment (If it's possible somehow).   The fun part is: both your and my first idea gives a fully functional  url, but my WampServer messing them up somehow ( by treating absolute paths as relatives?  I don't know.. maybe it's a configuration issue but i'm really lost at this point)

Comment: Can you just replace http_host with `/`, then echo your relative link? that might work. Really you want to look into setting up vhosts in your apache config, the problem is because localhost is the domain for all sites, which are in a subfolder and therefore not on `/`, but probably `/somesitefolder`

Comment: Have a look at this vhost. https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp/blob/master/build/httpd/httpd-vhosts.conf it's basically just like a .htaccess. rather than `http://localhost/somesubfolder`, you can set up `http://whatever-you-like`, and the subfolder will not be needed. then you just add `127.0.0.1 whatever-you-like` in c windows system32 drivers etc hosts